# ClearCase: How to write anything to Clearcase-managed directory?

Tags: version-control

I am completely new to ClearCase (I have mostly used SVN and some Git in the past).

I have spent some hours trying to write anything new into a directory managed by ClearCase. e.g. `mkdir foo` returns `mkdir: cannot create directory 'foo': Permission denied`.

When I have been unable to modify existing *files*, I can use the xcleartool GUI to checkout the file, which apparently allows me to then modify it. However, checking out the *directory* in xcleartool doesn't allow me to write to it.

How can I get write access to a ClearCase-managed directory? I don't want to change anything in the repository. I just want a local copy that I can modify and work with. At the moment, I'm considering copying and pasting the entire repository to somewhere usable, but I doubt ClearCase was intended to be used that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClearCase doesn't actually restrict permissions at a directory level - only at a file level.

In my case, the problem was simply that someone else had set the wrong permissions on the directory.

I don't have root access, so I had to hunt that person down to get it fixed. I hate not having root access!